# How to download a bash cgi headline http://?

Tags: bash, cgi

Sometime in the cgi bash was able to see the whole web address with http:

> "$VAR"$HTTP_HOST$REQUEST_URI
>   $VAR=http:// ← I do not remember as it is called a variable that showed http://

I searched all day and nothing can you know how variable called?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand.  Maybe look here: http://web.archive.org/web/20100217120428/http://hoohoo.ncsa.illinois.edu/cgi/env.html

Comment: RFC 3875 ‘CGI Version 1.1’ does not define such a variable. What do you expect to get from it except of `http`? `https`? Check the existence of `HTTPS` var then: `[[ -v HTTPS ]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC 3875 ‘CGI Version 1.1’ does not define such a variable. What do you expect to get from it except of `http`? If `https`, you have to check the existence of `HTTPS` variable:

```
if [[ -v HTTPS ]]; then
    SCHEME='https://'
else
    SCHEME='http://'
fi
```